# Swift: Load Images in UITable-View

Tags: ios, swift, image, caching, tableview

I have a tableview with custom cells that contain a picture (user-avatar).
I have implemented a simple solution for the cellForRowAt-Function with

```
            if let imgData = try? Data(contentsOf: imageUrl!), let img = UIImage(data: imgData) {                
                cell.profilePictureView.image = img
            }
```

However, it is very laggy and I have a few questions:

-> whats a good approach to set the images? just like below or should I load them asnynchronously?

-> Whats the best approach for the API-Service: is it ok to get all images individually (by requesting api/images/userid for each row) or is it better to include all the images directly in the server-reponse (that the list of e.g. 20 players is containing a picture-attribute)

-> does it make sense to cache the pictures? or does this kind of happens automatically? Whats a good approach to achieve this?

Comment: do it asynchronously this will make your table view scrolling fast as well.And it's better you Include images in server response.

Answer (score 0):

You should do all the "getting image" stuff on background thread and only going back to main thread to update UI. You can use 'sdwebimage'. This pod downloads image and cashes it for you (you don't have to worry about it).